# How do I enumerate network adapters on a Hyper-V guest using WMI?

Tags: c#, wmi, hyper-v

I've got a Hyper-V host, with several guests, each with one or more network adapters. How do I enumerate the network adapters on those guests?

Specifically, I'm looking for a particular guest, given a MAC address.

I'm using C# and `System.Management`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll leave out some of the details:

- Connect to Hyper-V on the host.
- Enumerate the machines (`SELECT * FROM Msvm_ComputerSystem`).
- For each machine, find the associated `Msvm_SyntheticEthernetPort` objects.

```
var ports = computerSystem.GetRelated("Msvm_SyntheticEthernetPort");
foreach (ManagementObject port in ports)
{
```

- Get hold of the settings:

```
    var portSettings = port.GetRelated("Msvm_SyntheticEthernetPortSettingData");
    foreach (ManagmentObject portSetting in portSettings)
    {
```

- Look for the configured MAC address:

```
        string macAddress = (string)portSetting .GetPropertyValue("Address");
```